# Pandas read_csv skipping a row

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a CSV file something like this:

```
" ";D1;D2;D3;D4;
" ";V1;V2;V3;V4;" ";
2014-03-03 00:00:00.0;397989;18.7;18.7;18.7;
2014-03-03 00:30:00.0;398042;18.7;18.7;18.6;
2014-03-03 01:00:00.0;398100;19;19;18.9;
```

First 2 rows are a multi header, the rest is data. I cannot change the CSV format even though there are is an extra redundant " " cell on line 2.

I've tried to parse the file as such (Pandas 0.12):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=[0,1], parse_dates=True)
df.head()

                  ( ,  )  (D1, V1)  (D2, V2)  (D3, V3)  (D4, V4)  \
0  2014-03-03 00:30:00.0    398042      18.7      18.7      18.6   
1  2014-03-03 01:00:00.0    398100      19.0      19.0      18.9   

   (Unnamed: 5_level_0,  )  
0                      NaN  
1                      NaN
```

Ignore the fact that there is a redundant column, I can drop that easily. The problem is that the first row (for timestamp 2014-03-03 00:00:00) is missing and I'm not sure why. Is this a linefeed setting perhaps I need?

If I further try to parse and specify an index column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=[0,1], parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
df.head()

                       (D1, V1)  (D2, V2)  (D3, V3)  (D4, V4)  \
2014-03-03 00:00:00.0                                           
2014-03-03 00:30:00      398042      18.7      18.7      18.6   
2014-03-03 01:00:00      398100      19.0      19.0      18.9   

                       (Unnamed: 5_level_0,  )  
2014-03-03 00:00:00.0                           
2014-03-03 00:30:00                        NaN  
2014-03-03 01:00:00                        NaN
```

I notice that the index is named after the first row after the header. This might be a clue.
Any ideas on how to handle that 1st missing row?

Comment: This loads fine using your first attempt in Pandas version 0.13.1

Comment: Yeah I just tried that and saw success too. Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade my stack just yet to 0.13, I have to find a 0.12 solution.

Comment: one option would be to pass `skiprows=2` to `read_csv` and add the column names after

Comment: bug in multi column parsing on 0.12. best to skip the rows then manually create the column multi index.

Comment: Right. Got it. Thanks folks.